# UIPanGestureRecognizer in section header view affects UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, uitableviewsectionheader

Really appreciate any idea or advice in what can cause such behavior in `Table View`? My upper cell is a section header view with custom implementation for deleting by adding `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to its view. And the row bellow is a 'classic' table view cell that has `commitEditingStyle` method. Why tapping on view in section header can “activate” this first row in the section? TIA for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in using this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer

Returning false fixed the problem